# GNU nano 4.8 infinite loop save file

Tags: nano

I can tell I'm not the first with this issue...

```
me@PF2DCSXD:/$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
cat: /etc/resolv.conf: No such file or directory

me@PF2DCSXD:/$ sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

I then get stuck in this infinite loop.

- `Ctrl + X`
- `Y` `Enter`
- It says "[ Error writing /etc/resolv.conf: No such file or directory ]"
- `Ctrl + C`

[image: GNU nano 4.8 window]

---

Terminal:

```
me@PF2DCSXD:/$ ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/etc/resolv.conf': File exists

me@PF2DCSXD:/$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
cat: /etc/resolv.conf: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file `/etc/resolv.conf` is, in all newer Ubuntu versions, a symbolic link, not an actual file. Create it with:

```
cd
sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf 
sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

As to your nano question, before saving the file, it must first be written, so the steps are to enter the text you wish, write it with Ctrl+o followed by Enter and finally exit nano with Ctrl+x followed by Enter.

Finally, your file is malformed, the proper term is nameserver, not namespace.

**EDIT**: In our chat, we determined that systemd, nor bashrc nor nano were working correctly. It is, however, desirable to have internet connectivity in order to download and install fixes. We therefore used vim to create a working resolv.conf. Upon writing and saving the `/etc/resolv.conf` file in vim, DNS resolution was restored allowing you to update and fix the server.

Comment: `$cat /etc/resolv.conf    cat: /etc/resolv.conf: No such file or directory`

Comment: I'll run all new steps again to make sure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134203/discussion-between-chili555-and-stressedboi-69420).